# Apply bold or italic to selected text in UITextView

Tags: ios, attributes, uitextview

How would I apply bold, italicized, and underlined text in a UITextView?  I have already done a bit of research and discovered that I can use "allowsEditingTextAttributes".  I have already applied this to my project, and the code can be seen below

```
//.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UITextView *allowEditing; 
}

@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsEditingTextAttributes;


//.m
@synthesize allowsEditingTextAttributes;

- (void) changeAttribute{
allowEditing.allowsEditingTextAttributes = YES;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html) **allowsEditingTextAttributes** allows *user* to change attributes of entered text. If you want to set default attributes for text typed by user - use **typingAttributes**, if you want some default text shown with attributes - use **attributedText** property.

Comment: This is actually what I wanted.  Would I just have to apply some bold, italic, etc buttons to my project?  And use an IBAction to allow them to make bolded text?